# _update_by_query + script do not work correctly，error:Trying to create too many scroll contexts

Tags: elasticsearch, update-by-query

**Elasticsearch version**: 7.6.2

**JVM**：13.0.2

**OS version**：centeros7

This is my code

```
POST  recommend_index/_update_by_query  

{
               "script": {
            "source": "ctx._source.rec_doctor_id = 1"
        },
               "query": {
                    "bool": {
                "must": [{
                            "terms": {
                                "id": ["22222"]
                            }
                             }]
                    }
                           }
         }
```

This code does not return the result correctly,The error message is

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "exception",
        "reason": "Trying to create too many scroll contexts. Must be less than or equal to: [5000]. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_open_scroll_context] setting."
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "Partial shards failure",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 1,
        "index": "recommend_index",
        "node": "XXX",
        "reason": {
          "type": "exception",
          "reason": "Trying to create too many scroll contexts. Must be less than or equal to: [5000]. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_open_scroll_context] setting."
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

I'm sure the current scroll is 0

When I replace _UPDATE_BY_QUERY with _UPDATE, it updates normally

No change has been made in ES since last Friday, and suddenly an error is reported

No configuration changes have been made to the ES server

Comment: When you get the error, can you immediately run `GET recommend_index/_stats?filter_path=**.scroll*` and update your question with the output you get?

Comment: "search": {
          "scroll_total": 658894,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 11430139,
          "scroll_current": 0
        }

Answer (score 1):

follow-up:
I set the search.max_open_scroll_context parameter to 5000 and found nothing to do with it.
I looked up the 7.6.2 release and found that someone was having the same problem as me.Link on this
here [#71354](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/71354) [#56202](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/56202)
I guess this is due to scrolling triggering the 7.6.2 bug.I restarted the cluster node without upgrading and found that it worked!!